# button.set_Image() doesn´t work good

Tags: image, python-2.7, button, pygtk

When I do a boton.set_Image() and reload the window, the button looks like this.

[image]

instead...

[image]

Comment: How can I change the image of gtk.button()?
When I try to use set_image(imagen), sometimes I got the image abobe

Comment: I didn´t update this when the window is hide, and it works good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used .setImage() to change the appareance and I didn´t refresh when the screen show again, because the image sometimes didn´t show well.